# I need to write an onEdit function for a Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the script I want to trigger:

```
function moveValuesOnly () {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var source = ss.getRange ("Copy!A1:N200");

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

}

**// I want moveValuesOnly to trigger once Cell A10 in the Validation tab changes to '2'**
```

I would greatly appreciate any help as I am a bit green at the moment.

Kind regards,

Brendon

Comment: so whats the issue, whats not working?

Comment: The above is not a trigger function, its only a function I have to still run. By triggering it I will be able to run it remotely from Appsheet, but I do not know how to write the onEdit script for it? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a read at [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Basically you can create any function and make it trigger using the [`ScriptApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app) class and those are called installable trigger.

But there are special functions that don't need to go through `ScriptApp` to get triggered, you just need to change the name of the function, and that would start enabling the trigger of those functions.

#### Simple trigger

Just change the name of the function so it will automatically start triggering.

```
function onEdit(e) {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var source = ss.getRange ("Copy!A1:N200");

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

}
```

#### Installable Trigger

Create another function to execute on time to create the trigger

```
function moveValuesOnly(e) {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var source = ss.getRange ("Copy!A1:N200");

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);

  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

}

function createTrigger(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveValuesOnly')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();

}
```

---

You have specified in your code that only want to trigger when the cell is A10, but this is impossible as of right now. You need to create an `if` statement making sure the range being edited is the one you care about.

Look at the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) because that would be input parameter of the trigger functions (`e`). That object has information about the range and spreadsheet being edited.

Basically make a condition with the `e` object

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;

  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  if(sheet.getName() == "<Your sheet name>" && newValue == 2 && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 10){
    // Browser.msgBox("Edit entered condition");
    //
    // Do your stuff here when the condition is satisfied 

  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that Raserhin. To clarify, once cell A10 changes to the value '2' it needs to trigger that script. How do I set that range and condition?

Comment: Basically you will need to build the condition yourself with the event object I left you an example with value `2` for `A10` cell, insert your sheet name and you will be good to go. The `onEdit` trigger will always execute you can only control the flow inside the trigger.

Comment: Hi @Raserhin, this is where I am at the moment then:

Comment: function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;

  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Appsheet" && newValue == 2 && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 10){
  Browser.msgBox("moveValuesOnly");
    

  } 
}

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Trigger1"

Comment: `onEdit` trigger is not a function you can execute in the editor an expect it to work, mainly because you need the input parameter. Go to modify the sheet so it triggers normally and then look the logs of the execution.